# How many minimum and maximum elements are there in a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $A = ${$X \in P(\{1,2,3.....10\}) : 2 \le |X| \le 7$} How many minum and maximum elements are in the partial order $(A, \subseteq)$ ?

I am not quite sure, but it seems to me that there should be 5 different subsets every of which has one minimum and one maximum. Am i right ? or is there an other solution?

Comment: The first thing to do is translate what it means for something to be a minimum or maximum in this partial order. A subset $A⊆\{1, ... , 10 \}$ is a minimum it doesn't contain any other subset of $\{1, ... , 10 \}$ that has size between $2$ and $7$. What properties does $A$ have to have to meet that condition?

Comment: @ZoeAllen Well to be a minimum means to have no other elements that are less. But I don’t understand why you say that A is a minimum, could you please clear that out ?

Comment: Oops I didn't notice $A$ had already been used in the question. I wasn't talking about $A$ from the question, and should have called it something else. What properties does an element $B$ of this particular poset have to have to not have any other elements less than it? (i.e. translating what 'less than' means in this particular poset).

Comment: "Well to be a minimum means to have no other elements that are less. " Be careful - we're not at all concerned with facts like "$4 \lt 6$" for this problem. All we care about is whether a set is a subset of another set.

Comment: @ZoeAllen hmm I think maybe a set B to be minimum means that it is a subset of all other sets ?

Comment: That would be the definition for a least element, which is a much stronger condition than being a minimum element in a partial order. What I meant though was what do you know about a minimal element of this poset in particular, which is specific to the way the order on this poset is defined. Not something that is true of any poset. I.e., if you know $B$ has size between $2$ and $7$, and you know it doesn't contain any proper subset of size between $2$ and $7$, what can you deduce about $B$?

Comment: @ZoeAllen well if it doesn’t contain any proper subset then it is  empty  or not in relation with any other

Comment: Not quite. If it didn't have any proper subsets at all, it would have to be size $0$ (empty) or there would be a set smaller than it which it contains. But it only has to not have any subsets of size between $2$ and $7$ (i.e. it can have subsets of size $0$ or $1$). So it can't be bigger than $2$, or there would be a size $2$ subset that it contains. But it can get away with being $2$ or smaller, as then the only proper subsets it contains are size $0$ or $1$, which aren't included.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Ok, thanks, got it,  but still can’t figure out the answer

Comment: The minimal elements will be precisely the elements which are size $2$, so the problem is just counting how many subsets of $\{1,...,10\}$ there are which are size $2$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen thanks a lot ! Really appreciate your help)!

Comment: In a partial ordered set, if a subset has a minimum, then it is unique. *The* minimum is the least element of a set. What you're calling minimum is a *minimal* element. The same for maximum and maximal.

Comment: @amrsa , Jean thanks !